# How to get the a number out of a string - C# - Regex

Tags: c#, html, regex

ok, here is my problem:

```
<div class="anime_info"><div class='ctdn'>Ep 7 - <span class="cd_day">3</span>d <span class="cd_hr">10</span>h <span class="cd_min">30</span>m </div>
```

How do i get the 7 out of the string using Regex. I try the fallowing:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(line,@"[^\d]")[0].Value
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(line,@"\d")[0].Value
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match (line, @">Ep (\d*)- <span").Groups [1].Value
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match (line, @">Ep ([0-9]*)- <span").Groups [1].Value
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match (line, @">Ep ([0-9])- <span").Groups [1].Value
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(line,@"\d").Value
```

All fail.

Please help and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You should parse the HTML instead of using regular expressions.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen You could use HTML Agility Pack to get to the element but still need RegEx to get the number from the  text.

Comment: @SteveWellens Sure. But narrowing down the search space before using a regular expression would be a good idea: Parse the HTML, find the text node you need, and then grab the number using a *simple* regex. Using regexes on HTML is rarely a good idea.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen "Using regexes on HTML is rarely a good idea"   Yes, that is why I suggested using HTML Agility Pack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will find a set of text that has a leading and trailing space with digits in between:

```
 (\d+)
```

Because it's a `\d+` it will find `1 or more` digits.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/8dYc9V_M8_UZh7ar)

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with `(?:Ep )(\d*)` - A non capturing group of "Ep " capturing the number following.

[Demo 1](https://www.debuggex.com/r/pKZ2jQukQgQjoXj5)

[Demo 2](http://regex101.com/r/iP2uJ0)

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code should work -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Test.Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string reference = "<div class=\"anime_info\"><div class='ctdn'>Ep 7 - <span class=\"cd_day\">3</span>d <span class=\"cd_hr\">10</span>h <span class=\"cd_min\">30</span>m </div>";

            var regex = "[>]Ep(\\s+)(\\d+)(\\s+)\\-(\\s+)[<]";
            var regex2 = "(\\d+)";
            foreach (var m in Regex.Matches(reference, regex))
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(m.ToString());
                var m2 = Regex.Match(m.ToString(), regex2);
                System.Console.WriteLine(m2.ToString());
            }
            System.Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

It prints the following, so it is working -

```
>Ep 7 - <
7
```

1. The first `regex` is for isolating the section containing `7`
2. The second `regex2` is for isolating `7` inside `regex`,
3. For safety, instead of using simple spaces I used `\\s+`, so if somehow more spaces are there, it won't fail.
4. By the way`-` is a key character in regex, so you should use `\-` if you are matching `-` in the string.

Answer (score 0):

From your regular expressions, it looks like you know that the "Ep " will always be there with the number followed by a space. One option would be to just break your string into a couple of substrings.

```
string input = "<div class='anime_info'><div class='ctdn'>Ep 7 - <span class='cd_day'>3</span>d <span class='cd_hr'>10</span>h <span class='cd_min'>30</span>m </div>";

//grab a substring starting after "Ep "
string next = input.Substring(input.IndexOf("Ep ") + 3);

//grab the start of the new string until the first space
string final = next.Substring(0, next.IndexOf(" "));
```

If you want to generalize this, you could do so with a function like

```
string stringBetween (string input, string start, string stop)
{
    //grab a substring starting after start
    string output = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(start) + start.Length);
    //grab the start of the new string until the first instance of stop
    output = output.Substring(0, output.IndexOf(stop));
    return output;
}
```

you would then just call

```
stringBetween(input, "Ep ", " ");
```

This also assumes you know that the first instance of `start` is followed by the value you want.